# How to create two seperate froms in sharepoint by using json format?

Tags: json, forms, sharepoint

I have created two different forms as a list on my sharepoint, I see there is another way i can customzie my format, configuring layout. Below is my logic, but need help at the center of the form it must have an image and toggle button move these forms from left to righ(right means another form and left im returning to normal form as previous).

`{ "sections": [ { "displayname": "Finding Information", "fields": [ "Finding-Description", "Due date" ] }, { "displayname": "Root Cause", "fields": [ "Root Cause" ] }, { "displayname": "Corrective Action", "fields": [ "Corrective Action" ] }, { "displayname": "Status", "fields": [ "Status" ] }, { "displayname": "Attachments", "fields": [ "Attachments" ] } ], "buttons": [ { "name": "Save", "position": "left" }, { "name": "Submit for Approval", "position": "right", "inactive": true }, { "name": "Close", "position": "right" } ], "conditional_hide": { "sections": [ { "name": "Status", "values_to_hide": [ "Draft" ] } ], "fields": [ { "name": "Request Action", "values_to_hide": [ "Draft" ] }, { "name": "Submit for Approval", "values_to_hide": [ "Draft" ] }, { "name": "Complete Approval", "values_to_hide": [ "Draft" ] } ] } }`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide some screenshots of the form to better understand the issue.

Comment: @Community, i end up using Power Apps, has this option for me. I thought by using Microsoft List for using JSON per column, it will give me the options to create one but has some limititations